# Movie where a crashed alien spaceship is discovered on Earth, with frozen alien bodies in the walls of the craft

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I watched a movie when I was about 7 or 8 with my grandma, maybe younger. It may have been 1990 when I saw it, but I have the idea it's from the '70s or '80s.

I believe it aired on TV and it was a sci-fi movie about some scientists or maybe a reporter who were investigating a UFO that had been found. The UFO had the bodies of aliens in the craft, frozen in the walls. They were very small and I think that it was a man and a woman who were excavating them out of the walls, or they were watching others try to dig them out.

I remember very little about it other than that, but it's bothered me for probably 30 years now. It was in color and I definitely think it aired on television.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you think of any more details, no matter how small, please edit your question to add them. And if anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Did the aliens look similar to humans or very different?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is remeniscent of Quatermass and the Pit, released in 1967.
An alien spacecraft is discoverered during excavations in London. Alien bodies are found in a chamber in the craft. Also the investigators are subjected to psychic influences in the course of their work.

Comment: *Quatermass and the Pit* is B&W, and the OP states that the movie he is looking for is in color.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen, Quatermass and the Pit is in colour.  Only the first two Quatermass films were B&W.

Comment: There are two film versions of QatP - a B&W from 1958 and a colour  one from 1967.

Comment: @MikeStone The B&W version of QatP wasn't a film but a six-part television series

Comment: This is it! Thank you. I remember now the whole part about the lady being affected psychically after watching a clip. I am 100% this is the right one.  Thank you so much for the help! It has been driving me bonkers the majority of my life!

Comment: @Wstargirl84 It is surprising both how these unresolved memories keep nagging us, and how helpful this site and the helpful people populating it are in resolving them! I have found a few stories here myself that didn't even disappoint me after many years (*Thus we fooled Charlemagne* is still a treasure...).

Comment: Originally released in the U.S. as *Five Million Years to Earth*.

Comment: @Gordon D - The 1958 QatP has been on TV several times as a feature film, and indeed I have a dvd of it in that form.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, any links to **anything** about _"Thus we fooled Charlemagne"_? Googling for that exact phrase returns nothing, only increasing my curiosity! 

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Sorry to send you on a wild goose chase! My bad: The title is *Thus We **Frustrate** Charlemagne* (as an aside, note the present tense ...). It's quirky and stayed in my mind for decades after I read it. My second error appears to be that apparently I found the story through other means than this website, unless it swallows questions. The story is available online in the internet archive [here](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v25n03_1967-02/page/n125/mode/2up).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, thank you!  Only a couple paragraphs in and already taken.  :)  The imagery!  Wonderfully archaic view of high-tech.  _"All it took was a cable, **no more than a yard in diameter**..."_    Oh my goodness!  And now we do so much wirelessly anyway.  Fun stuff!

Comment: @MikeStone I seem to remember reading that the BBC edited the six episodes into two ninety-minute parts so not surprising if somebody joined those together!

Answer (score 6):

Might this be ***[Wavelength](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086571/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (1983)...?

From IMDB:

> Two young lovers learn that a small group of child-like space aliens are marooned on Earth and are being held prisoner at a top secret military facility. The couple then decide to liberate the extraterrestrial castaways and help them make a rendezvous with a rescue ship sent from the alien home planet.

From a [user review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2309852/?ref_=tt_urv):

> Low budget "E-T" like movie even though it was written years before the film "E-T" was even in production **the movie "Wavelength" has to do with a trio of captured aliens who's space craft was blown out of the sky over the Mojave Desert by a super secret US military laser device. The three alien spacemen, named by the scientists and military who are examining of them, Gamma Beta & Delta, Dov Young Josh Oreck & Christian Morris, are put on ice in a secret military installation,** that been out of operation since the end of WWII,in the Hollywood Hills.
>
> It's when the ultra sensitive to both whale dolphin and alien brainwaves **Iris Longacer, Cherie Corrie, picks up the alien spacemen, who look like pre-teenage boys, cries for help that she gets her boyfriend down in the dumps rock guitarist Bobby Sinclair, Robert Carradine, to help her find them.** It takes a while but with the help of desert prospector and former military construction contractor Dan, Keean Wynn, the aliens are tracked down to the long abandoned military installation that the US military is keeping them locked up, in cold storage, in.

What matches:

- A film from the early '80s.
- An alien spaceship has crashed on Earth.
- The aliens are small, resembling bald, human children.
- They spend a good chunk of the movie in cryogenic stasis pods.
- A young couple attempts to free them.

What doesn't match:

- The aliens aren't shown to be frozen in the walls of the spacecraft, but are put into stasis after being discovered by the government and taken to a secret facility.

The whole film is up on YouTube, but this trailer covers most of the relevant points.

Comment: It is Quartermass and the Pit. HOWEVER, I have been aggressively searching the Internet for 3 days for 4 movies or TV episodes that I have been looking for for almost 30 years and Wavelength was one of them. I could remember the couple taking the three aliens to the desert where they sat and did something projected light from their bodies. I managed to find three of the four and this was the last one. So glad to finally be able to stop wondering about it all!

Answer (score 4):

I know this movie. It left an indelible mark upon my grey matter as a child and haunts me to this day. Something about hordes of praying manti/grasshoppers going off a cliff to their demise just creeped me out for some reason. The impenetrable bluish skin of the spacecraft had my attention as well. Anyway, I digress.
I do not recall the exact number of millions, but the title was:
"______ million years to earth"
Pretty sure this is your flick.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  *Five Million Years to Earth* was the U.S. title of *Quatermass and the Pit*, which is the accepted answer.

Comment: Wow. Another impression that lasted long!